# How to trigger an event from parent window based on iframe content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm creating a widget using iframe, and I want to hide the iframe in a specific event.

Let's say **main.html** file has:

```
<div id="my_widget">
  <iframe src="www.mysite.com/main.html" width="50%" frameborder="0" height="550" id="my_iframe">Error uploading the frame.</iframe>
</div>
```

**widget.html** file contains:

```
<div id="widget-status-div" status="success"></div>
```

I tried to add some script by end of the widget.html file to access parent window (main.html) like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
    setTimeout(function(){
      parent.$("#my_widget").fadeOut(300, function() { parent.$("#my_widget").remove(); });
    }, 3000);       
</script>
```

But unfortunately it didn't work.

Another thing I tried to do, is to set **setInterval(check_iframe, 5000)** at parent window(main.html) to keep checking **widget-status-div** div at iframe every 5 seconds, but the problem is that I can't check the content of the iframe somehow (or maybe I'm doing it wrong).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm using Rails and routing widget to main.html. Anyway I'll update the question for clarity. but this is not the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fail most likley due to the same-origin-policy. It restricts JavaScript access from one protocol and domain to another.

[image: Same Origin Policy results]

For more information about this you can check out the [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

To achieve cross origin communication you can use the messaging API defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

With this api you can define an event listener on one file and a trigger in the other.

Listen to messages:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;

  // ...
}
```

Post a message to another document:

```
var parentWindow = window.parent;

// When the popup has fully loaded, if not blocked by a popup blocker:

// This does nothing, assuming the window hasn't changed its location.
parentWindow.postMessage("The user is 'bob' and the password is 'secret'",
                  "https://secure.example.net");
```

You can checkout the complete example in the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)

Comment: Thanks for your willing ti help, but my problem is with sending the parent window, in your example, you mentioned popup, how can I specify parent window to send data to (assuming the parent window is not at the same domain)

Comment: Just use `window.parent` instead of popup. I edited the examples.

Comment: I'll double check it one more time, but I tried to use parent before to access some of the tags from the parent and didn't work out, like window.parent.$("#my_widget"). If i'm not mistaken I guess you can't access parent unless you are at the same domain. I'll double check it and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: That's right. You wont be able to access the parent if it doesn't fit the same-origin-policy. There is just one way to do a cross origin communication: The messaging API. You have to insert `window.parent.postMessage` into the iframe document. And the `window.addEventListener("message", handler, false);` in your parent document.